# How can I achieve something like "from foo.bar import baz.qux"?

Tags: python, module, package, python-2.x, import

I have a few packages that include modules named `util`, so that it becomes difficult to tell which `util` module is referred to if you see something like this:

```
util.some_func()
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
views.util.some_func()
```

...but I can't figure out a good way to import this.  Of course this doesn't work:

```
from apture.main import views.util
```

The best I can come up with is to add `from . import views` in `views/__init__.py`, and then do this:

```
from apture.main import views
views.util.some_func()
```

Is there any better way to do this?  The only other alternative I can think of is:

```
import apture.main.views.util
from apture.main import views

views.util.some_func()
```

...but that's a bit ugly.

Comment: Loading submodules in `__init__` is the standard way to do it. We are talking about Python, so there is no better way than the standard way.

Answer (score 4):

Would this work for you:

```
  from apture.main.view import util as view_util
```

Comment: I may be overly picky, but I don't really like substituting underscores for dots that way.  I suppose it's just that I have some idea that `view.util` is a submodule in the `view` package, whereas I have to look at the top of the file to tell what `view_util` is.  Regardless, it's beginning to sound like I might not have any choices that meet my requirements.  :-)